# How to copy maven Dependencies to ouput artifact WEB-INF/lib in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I know in eclipse maven can copy dependencies to WEB-INF/lib dir by  `setting 'Deployment Assembly' and 'Build Path'`, but how can I achieve this with Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I find a solution:

In `Intellij IDEA`, a Web application archive (**WAR**) is called an [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/artifact.html?origin=old_help). 
And you can achieve adding libraries automatically by setting the artifact:

- Open `Project Structure` setting window
- Navigate：`Project Settings --> Artifacts --> **war exploded --> Output Layout --> WEB-INF`
- Then create a directory named lib under WEB-INF, right click the lib folder, you will see `Add Copy of-` option.
- Select `Library Files` and add the libraries you want. [**Tips**: `Ctrl + A` can work here to add all files]

Answer (score 1):

`Maven` is based around the central concept of a **build lifecycle**. What this means is that the process for **building** and **distributing** a particular artifact (project) is clearly defined.

### A Build Lifecycle is Made Up of Phases

> Each of these build lifecycles is defined by a different list of build phases, wherein a build phase represents a stage in the lifecycle.

For example, the default lifecycle comprises of the following phases (for a complete list of the lifecycle phases, refer to the Lifecycle Reference):

- `validate` - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
- `compile` - compile the source code of the project
- `test` - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
- `package` - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
- `verify` - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met
- `install` - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
- `deploy` - done in the build environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

`Maven` Project have its own type of Project architecture. 
So during `installation` process all dependencies are added to the `/lib` Folder. these dependencies are part of `pom.xml`.

Thank you.

Comment: I have found the solution, but still thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

IDE is just tools to code. To help you with assembling/packing the deployable artifact, like a war file, we should rely on the build tools. Maven, Gradle, Ant or whatever you're using should have a ways to configure dependencies to copy to WEB-INF/libs. And either Eclipse or IntelliJ will understand those configurations.