# Tomcat server can't found DigestUtils apache class

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

While building a web application, I used the class DigestUtils from org.apache.commons.codec.digest.

When I'm testing the class using it, I have no problems and everything compile and run as expected.

But when I'm using it with Tomcat (like in a servlet), I got the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils
```

I've done some research on the problem, and can't found a solution that help me.

The problem append sometimes on others of my developments, so I would like to know how to solve this problem for all of my futur works.

I know that Java 9 doesn't include all of the modules by default, and I've read some questions that solution lead being in classpath ?

I'm currently using the IDE IntelliJ IDEA, can you help me to get rid of this ?

The part of the call which use DigestUtils is :

```
private String hash(String value) {
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(value);
}
```

*I know that md5 is deprecated, but it is a client requirement.*

The application is running under Tomcat 9.0.4

**Edit :**

- I've add commons-codec to maven, and if I check the project dependencies, she's in, so the problem is as expected Tomcat which cannot use it...

[IntelliJ Maven commons-codec dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khQVM.png)

**Answer :**

IntelliJ does not include all library from maven dependencies into the WEB-INF/lib.

*See :*

- Midhun response
- [How to copy maven Dependencies to ouput artifact WEB-INF/lib in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084129/how-to-copy-maven-dependencies-to-ouput-artifact-web-inf-lib-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Maven for your project. Make sure that apache common codec jar is available in the classpath, or added part of your web application dependency.

Comment: I've tried to add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11 as a maven dependency, but it doesn't change the result... From the fact that tests runs, it is surely Tomcat which cannot access to the library, how can I told him to load it from the project ?

Comment: Tomcat uses web app classes loader. So as long as the jar is packaged in the WEB-INF/lib of the application, it should work. Make sure that the maven dependency is not using "provided" scope, so that it will be packaged in the web application

Comment: The maven dependency isn't in provided scope. I don't understand why should I move the library to WEB-INF/lib while other like mongodb driver  works fine ?

Comment: I found the answer, IntelliJ automatically add mongodb driver to the output-layer (I edit with the answer, thanks for the indication on WEB-INF/lib)